# Errcode: 2, WordPress unable to create/write to file

Tags: mysql, fedora, system-administration

So I've asked around basically everywhere (including here) but I'm going to try again because literally noone seems to want to help and I'm desperate af.

```
[Fri Dec 13 06:52:28.286593 2013] [:error] [pid 13101] [client 124.169.101.176:62647] WordPress database error Can't create/write to file '/var/tmp/#sql_1ff_0.MAI' (Errcode: 2) for query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('post_tag') ORDER BY t.name ASC LIMIT 50 made by do_accordion_sections, call_user_func, wp_nav_menu_item_taxonomy_meta_box, get_terms, referer: http://wardport.com/wordpress/wp-admin/nav-menus.php
```

As you can see from that^ I'm getting errcode 2, which by `perror 2` means "No such file or directory". Most sources tell me that a) there is no space to work in the directory, which there is (it's actually completely empty!) or b) mysql doesn't have permission to write to said directory (/var/tmp/) which it does (desperate attempt http://puu.sh/5LeRg.png).

What the hell is wrong my server this is so frustrating

Comment: Ok does the file `#sql_1ff_0.MAI` exist in that directory? Also I might suggest backup up the file if it does exist and then try this command `chown mysql:mysql /var/tmp/#sql_1ff_0.MAI`

Comment: The file does not exist, I am under the impression that WordPress was trying to create the file rather than edit it (it never existed in the first place)

Comment: Weird.My var folder is owned by root and in the group root. All folders contained within besides www, are owned by root and in the group root. www and all folders within are owned by www-data and in the group www-data. Maybe this is the issue. The fact that your var is owned by mysql and in the group mysql makes me think something is not quite right there. I would maybe think about changing the owner and groups of your files obviously being careful not to kill the server. Also a MAI file is apparently an MS Mail file. Which is equally strange. All my searches seem to be following you around.

Comment: .MAI is used for AriaDB files, provided with the MariaDB fork of MySQL.

Comment: @OllieJones I learn more from this site than anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This file you can't create seems to be an AriaDB container file for a temporary table.  Are you running MariaDB?  If so, what version?

A temp file is not strange for this query.

Your mysqld is somehow misconfigured, or perhaps the server running it is misconfigured.

Do you have access to a simple (non-WordPress) mysql client? If so, try the same query there just to rule out the whole WordPress / PHP infrastructure as the cause of the problem.  If that query fails, try a simpler one like

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts
```

This one may not fail, because it doesn't need to create and then sort a temp table. The point is to get a simple test case that fails.  Don't overthink this, just get yourself a simple query that fails.

Is this your own server? If so, you should be able to find an error log for your mysqld process. It is probably a file with a name ending in .err someplace in your MySQL data directory.  tail it (look at the last few hundred lines) and see if mysqld is explaining in more detail what's wrong. Run your simple failing test case query and look again.

/var/tmp should be writeable by every user on the system; *nix falls over in a heap if it isn't. It should also have plenty of space on it.

FWIW, this isn't a programming question (unless you're working on the internals of the version of MySQL you're using). It's a sysadmin question.

Comment: I'm running MariaDB yes, version "5.5.33a-MariaDB". Would phpMyAdmin be a simple non-WordPress mysql client? I'll try it anyway. If you like, I can also add the last few hundred lines of my MySQL logs to a pastebin and give you the link.
Added sysadmin to the tags.

Comment: PMA gives same error, `#1 - Can't create/write to file '/var/tmp/#sql_1ff_0.MAI' (Errcode: 2)`, however your simple query executes without a problem.

Comment: It seems that your instance of MariaDB can't create temp files to finish carrying out queries.  So you need to troubleshoot why the mysqld user can't create files in /var/tmp. Is /var/tmp full (`df /var/tmp`)? Are the protections, including the suid / sgid bits, set incorrectly?  I'm taking the wordpress and php tags off this question.

Comment: Hey Ollie, /var/tmp was not full and I do not know about the protections, I'll have to play around with those another time. For now it's fixed, as I posted in my answer to my own question. Is there any way as marking this question as closed?
Thankyou so much for helping though. I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB is trying to create temporary table while execution SELECT for sorting.

I wonder if you change MySQL variable `tmpdir` to `/tmp`

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES like '%tmp%';
+-------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name     | Value           |
+-------------------+-----------------+
...
| tmpdir            | /var/tmp        | <= probably, current value is '/var/tmp'
+-------------------+-----------------+

[mysqld]
user    = ...
port    = ...
basedir = ...
datadir = ...
tmpdir  = /tmp  <= change here and restart MariaDB
...
```

### UPDATE

I not sure `service mysqld restart` has the functionality changing option when startup. But, `mysql.server` has this. probably `mysql.server` is `/etc/rc.d/init.d/` (assuming CentOS or Fedora). Could you try this?

```
$ ./mysql.server start --tmpdir=/tmp
```

I have tested with own my server. `tmpdir` is changed well.

Comment: Hey InoS, that is what the current value was. I've changed it in my.cnf to `tmpdir = /tmp`, and used `service mariadb restart` as well as `service mysqld restart` but when I run your query `SHOW VARIABLES like '%tmp%'; I still get tmpdir = /var/tmp. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlexWard Humm, weird. maybe you've edited wrong my.cnf? I have updated.

Comment: As far as I know there is only one my.cnf, I have also tried starting the server with the command `service mysqld --tmpdir=/tmp start` as the one you suggested didn't work. `tmpdir` is still apparently set to /var/tmp! 
My my.cnf file: http://pastebin.com/3zZ9etXU, located at /etc/my.cnf

Comment: @AlexWard sorry i can't figur out any more. It's 00:52 am here. Lastly I wonder if ` /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf`has tmpdir or other files in /etc/my.cnf.d/ or your MariaDB had chroot option else where.

Comment: I'll take a look and keep trying, thanks so much for your help though!! :)

Answer (score 0):

So basically I completely gave up, did a thorough cleansing of my server, uninstalling MariaDB and deleting all of my databases along with it (wasn't much in them to begin with, although I'm sure it wouldn't have hurt to back them up and restore them later :P). I then restarted my server, reinstalled MariaDB & Re-ran the WordPress install and voilà everything worked.

It may be that only one step of this process fixed the problem, E.G. I may have simply needed to reboot my server to fix things up. If you have this same error give it a go!

Thanks again to everyone for trying to help. :)